# How can I properly translate possessive form of nouns?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, sentence-translation, translation-explanation

"Pater Iūliae est Iūlius". Would this be "**Julia's father** is Julius", or "**The father of Julia** is Julius"? I feel like it's missing some words to be the latter.
Does it matter? How can I tell?

Comment: Don't these mean exactly the same thing?

Comment: @MPW They are perfect synonyms, yes. I'm not even sure if they differ all that much in register

Answer (score 12):

In general, don't focus on every word having an equivalent in the other language. For example, the single word *magistrō* would generally be translated into multiple words like "to the master". That's just how translation works—focus on translating the overall *meaning*, not finding an equivalent to each and every word.

In English, we have multiple ways of combining nouns. We can use *Y's X*, which is the way we inherited from Anglo-Saxon, or we can use *X of Y*, which we borrowed from French. There are some places where you can use one but not the other, which come down to differences between French and Anglo-Saxon grammar, but for the most part it's a matter of style.

In Classical Latin, on the other hand, there's just one way: the genitive. So whether you translate it with *'s* or *of* comes down to what sounds better in context in English. (Sometimes you can also turn a noun into an adjective in Latin, like *pater Jūliānus est Jūlius*, but this is a lot more restricted than the *'s* and *of* in English. When this happens, you'll often end up translating it into *'s* or *of*, just like the genitive.)